# Git Checkout hangs indefinitely with git bash. How to solve?

Tags: git, bash, git-checkout

I have been working on a project in the develop branch using git bash on my work computer.  I have just attempted to checkout to the master branch as I intend to merge the changes, but when I attempt to do this the command line hangs indefinitely until I kill it with CTRL + C.

If I attempt to checkout again, I get the following error:

> Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
>       an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
>       are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
>       may have crashed in this repository earlier:
>       remove the file manually to continue.

However, after deleting the index.lock file, attempting to use git checkout once again simply hangs in the terminal and never makes any progress until I kill the process once again!  Etc.!

Has anyone come across this, and if so, how did you go about solving this issue?

Comment: Can you try with `GIT_TRACE=1` in front of you command, and report where it gets stuck?

Comment: The output I get from that is `15:11:16.365303 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'checkout' 'master'`

Comment: Does it work if you run `git worktree add` and pass another folder as the checkout destination? Maybe Git is waiting for some other process to remove the lock on files.

Comment: Also try some tool like LockHunter to check if any files inside your work tree are in use.

Comment: Seems to be working now, although I'm not totally sure what I did to get it to work!

Comment: The git 2.11.1.windows.1 I'm using hangs on checkout whenever it wants to remove a file which is in use as executable (possibly some tool you just started up). Procmon shows "CANNOT DELETE" six times.I vaguely recall that older git versions returned with an error rather than hanging. The worst is that closing the file in use doesn't cause git to continue normal operation, you have to kill it (Ctrl-C), remove the lock file and relaunch it.

Answer (score 4):

I've been having the same issue very recently and it appears to be related to Sublime Text's aggressive indexing locking files in my tree - if you're using ST then try deleting the lock file, closing ST and then running `git checkout master` again.

Comment: I did manage to fix this in the end, although to be perfectly honest I'm not totally sure what I did! I was using Visual Studio Code, not Sublime, but it may have simply been a case of closing down the text editor in between removing the lock file that solved it - honestly couldn't say for sure as this was a while ago!

Comment: I just googled this because I was having the same problem.  It fixed itself when I realized that in addition to the git bash shell (I'm on Windows) I had a command shell open and was in a directory in the repo.  Closing the command shell fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Related the the answer above. I had this issue with Eclipse and Git Shell on Windows.

You may have followed these steps to get into this situation:

1. Create a branch.
2. Modify a file in Eclipse (or Sublime i expect) and leave it open.
3. Add the file and commit then push branch to origin.
4. Git status says nothing the commit.
5. Try to checkout the original branch - it hangs.

To resolve the issue:

6. So Ctrl-C and delete the lock file.
7. Note that git status now says `modified: filename`
8. Switch to Eclipse and it says 'file has changed on disk - with option to reload.
9. Close the file in Eclipse.
10. Undo the changes with `git checkout -- filename`

Now it should be possible to checkout the branch.

Answer (score 1):

I had Textpad open on a file, and I think its locking caused this (same as spiralx mentioned about Sublime Text's aggressive indexing locking files). Even though I closed Textpad, I still could not switch the branch. I rebooted my VM, and then all was well - no more hanging. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, when created and explored new folder with Total Commander.

My solution was:

1. Ctrl-C and delete the lock file
2. **Close Total Commander**
3. `git status` - check if previous attempt to checkout branch changed something.
4. Undo the changes with `git checkout -- .` This resets all uncommited changes!

Now I can checkout the branch.

Comment: `git checkout --` was the only thing that worked for me. Other answers did not work. Thanks!